# Mysql real escape string loop multiple variables

Tags: php, variables, mysql-real-escape-string

Say I want to insert into name, address, city, state, zip values $name, $address Etc.....

How can I run `mysql_real_escape_string` on each of the variables before inserting. There has got to be a foreach or loop or while method instead of writing out each variable right?

Thanks for the help.

Tom

so if I have

```
 $data = array($address, $city, $name);
 array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $data);
```

and

```
$columns = "name, address, city, state, zip";
$count = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO customer($columns) VALUES ($data)");
```

I get a ton of errors.

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /Users/tommyscott45/Sites/experiment/result.php on line 23
```

now what?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using it at all. You should be using bound parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database error has occurred when trying to invoke `mysql_real_escape_string` and I see that you're using `$dbh->exec()` to execute the query. This suggests that you connect to the database with PDO, so you should rather use [`PDO::quote`](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Moreover, as others have already mentioned, a better way to solve your problem would be to use prepared statements and [`PDO::prepare`](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: Now I have to learn all about PDO stuff, this is so frustrating, I know what I want to accomplish but don't have the vocabulary to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

You use sprintf.

For example

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT into 
                  TABLE name = '%s', address = '%s', city = '%s'",
                 mysqli_escape_string($link, $name), 
                 mysqli_escape_string($link, $address), 
                 mysqli_escape_string($link, $city) );
```

Or is that not exactly what you were looking for; a way to avoid typing "mysqli_escape_string" over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$data = array($address, $city, $name);
array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $data);
```

But you really should not use the mysql extension anymore. Have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) and their support for "prepared statements".

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems.

First is that you need to assign the output of `array_map()` to a variable as it doesn't do in-place conversion. Then you need to implode it back to a string.

```
 $data = "'".implode("', '", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $data))."'";
```

The bigger problem is that you're hand assembling SQL instead of using a data access layer which would take the information you're wanting to save and use its knowledge about where you want to store it to assemble a correct SQL statement, with proper quoting and all.

This is also the impetus behind suggestions to use prepared statements, incidentally, but just using prepared statements is only half of the solution because you would still be assembling SQL statements.